# Excel Word Wrap + disappearing text

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2003

Why dooes adding word wrap to a column in Excel cause it to stop showing text on some computers? If I send the file to someone else, they see the text, but on my computer the text does not show uip in the column.

Comment: Have you tried making the column wider?

Comment: yes. That did not fix the problem. I already know the answer and posted it. I put it here so others won't have to waste so much time on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question may seem very strange, but I wrote the question as well as the answer here because I spent a few days trying to resolve this problem, only to realize it had the most ridiculous answer:

Sometimes when you are using dual screens in Windows XP with Office 2003, this will happen. The resolution is to close Excel, disable your second monitor, then reopen Excel (all the data should be visible again), and then you can re-enable the second monitor.